# building and using a library(assimp) in linux

Tags: linux, terminal, linker, g++

I'm trying to use assimp(on linux) for loading 3D models into my project and building the library itself is very easy since it has a `cMakeLists.txt` file that automates the build process. But, once the library is built it provides the a folder `assimp` with the structure:

[image]

I think the three major folders to note here are the `bin`, the `lib` and the `include`

My project structure is basically like this:

[image]

The command I would use for compiling before `assimp` was in my project requirement was this:

```
> g++ -std=c++17 -I/home/user/lighting/mLib main7.cpp -o main.out -lGL -lglfw -lGLU
```

But, now I am confused with these things:

1. Am I supposed to link to the binary in the `bin` or the `lib` files
   in the `assimp/lib` folder.
2. I have included the header files in my source code and specified the
   include path, but how am I supposed to link to the libraries of the
   assimp?
3. There are 4 `lib` files inside the `assimp/lib` folder, which ones
   am I supposed to link to?
4. Even though I'm using make to automate the build, but what would be
   the  terminal command to build the project linking the assimp
   library?

I try to use the following but it throws an `-lassimp` not found error:

```
> g++ -std=c++17 -I/home/user/lighting/mLib -L/home/user/lighting/assimp/lib main7.cpp -o main.out -lGL -lglfw -lGLU -lassimp
```